# How can we check our solution is valid or in ad array that their will be no repetition in number in column and rows in java eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I made my own program which check that our solution is valid or not in 2D array which check that there is not repetition of number in rows and column but it not work please help me to make this program or check it I post it 
after run this program my eclipse does not work

```
public class assigh1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] a={{8,3,5,4,1,6,9,2,7}, 
                   {2,9,6,8,5,7,4,3,1}, 
                   {4,1,7,2,9,3,6,5,8}, 
                   {5,6,9,1,3,4,7,8,2},
                   {1,2,3,6,7,8,5,4,9}, 
                   {7,4,8,5,2,9,1,6,3}, 
                   {6,5,2,7,8,1,3,9,4},
                   {9,8,1,3,4,5,2,7,6},
                   {3,7,4,9,6,2,8,1,5}};
        int x,y;
        for(int i=0; i<9; i++) {
            for(int j=0; j<9; j++) {
                x=a[i][j];
                for(int k=i; k<i+1; k++){
                    for(int l=j+1; l<9; l++) {
                        if(x==a[k][l]) {
                            System.out.print("invalid solution");
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                y=a[j][i];
                for(int m=j; m<j+1; j++) {
                    for(int n=i; n<9; n++) {
                        if(y==a[n][m]) {
                            System.out.print("invalid solution");
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("your solution is valid");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code, I'm assuming that the numbers are restricted to 1 to 9.

This is a bit hacky but you can certain do this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] a={{8,3,5,4,1,6,9,2,7}, 
               {2,9,6,8,5,7,4,3,1}, 
               {4,1,7,2,9,3,6,5,8}, 
               {5,6,9,1,3,4,7,8,2},
               {1,2,3,6,7,8,5,4,9}, 
               {7,4,8,5,2,9,1,6,3}, 
               {6,5,2,7,8,1,3,9,4},
               {9,8,1,3,4,5,2,7,6},
               {3,7,4,9,6,2,8,1,5}};
    checkArray(a);
}

public static void checkArray(int[][] a) {
    //container is a temporary storage to count how many of that value we counted as we iterate through the 2d array
    int[] container = new int[9];

    //this is for horizontal validation
    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
            container[a[i][j] - 1]++; //this is for rows
            if(hasRepeats(container)) {
                System.out.println("invalid solution");
                return;
            }
        }
        //reset the container
        container = new int[9];
    }

    //this is for vertical validation
    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
            container[a[j][i] - 1]++; //this is for columns
            //we have it checked here so that if we find a repeat, we can exit right away
            if(hasRepeats(container)) {
                System.out.println("invalid solution");
                return;
            }
        }
        //reset the container
        container = new int[9];
    }

    //if it passes through everything, then the 2d array is good
    System.out.println("your solution is valid");
}

//this method checks to see if anything was repeated; return true if it finds one
public static boolean hasRepeats(int[] container) {
    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        if(container[i] > 1) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: eclipse says that its main method not found in this class what would i do for that

Comment: i post it now   in new question form plz read it and tell me ans

Comment: Just replace all the code below initializing the 2d array by calling `checkArray(a);`

Comment: thank u so much bt please can you explain me step by step once whats it do i'll be very thankfull to you

Comment: i want to make it algo so please ans me upper last question

Comment: I explained a bit inside the code through the comment. You should try to read the code and follow it step by step as this will be a good skill to learn.

Comment: Also, don't forget to accept the answer as this'll help others as well. Thanks!

Comment: will you tell me a small program of Boolean which help me to understand the boolean working in java

Comment: i want to make my own project in java how i can do this from my own coad

Comment: one thing more tell me that what is the units if quality of software plz tell me 5-10

Comment: i have different classes in java and want to made my own java project which use when i call it like import java.util.scanner or import java.util.* same like this please tell me how can i do that 
it is very important for me how i can do this or tell me my question is valid or not 
we can just access it from other project or just make the a specific project which we can import in our new program please tell me clearly my small code is here 
CODE IS HERE in downward cment

Comment: package saj;import java.util.Scanner; public class AsignmentNO2 {Scanner input =new Scanner(System.in);  public void LSEARCH(int len,int Array[]) System.out.print("Your Array before operation is "); for(int i=0;i<len;i++){System.out.print(Array[i]+",");} System.out.printf("\nEnter the  element u want to search:");int pos=input.nextInt(); for(int i=0;i<len;i++){if (Array[i]==pos){System.out.println("Your element loction is :"+(i+1));
   System.out.println("your element original location in the array is:"+i);}}
   System.out.printf("\n\n\n");}

Comment: plz bata do koi kya karan